# How to open App info Page of Android System WebView in Android

Tags: android, android-webview

My App is crashing when user does not have Android System WebView enabled in Android 10 and Android 11.

So I decided to show a Dialog to users that tells them that the Android System WebView is disabled and they need to enable it.

In the dialog box I have an error text and a button. **I want to open this error page when user clicks the button on the Dialog.**

[image]

#### My Questions are

1. Is it even possible to open this page from my Activity ?
2. If yes then how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi it's possible to open that view using code.
This is java version

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", "com.google.android.webview", null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It works like a charm.  How did you get the package name? com.google.android.webview

Comment: I googled a bit and found this on Playstore, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview
The query string `id` in a url is a package name

Comment: Got it. I tested with with another app packages as well. We just need to grab the app package name and put in the Uri. It will open the settings page. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it fixed your problem